# Isomorphism between $R/P$ and $R_P/PR_P$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism, ring-isomorphism

Let R be a commutative ring, and P a prime bilateral ideal. Let $R_P = \left\{ \frac{a}{s} \ \middle\vert \ a \in R, \ s \not \in P \right\}$ and $PR_P = \left\{ \frac{a}{s} \ \middle\vert \ a \in P, \ s \not \in P \right\}$

I'm trying to prove that the map
$$
    \begin{gather*}
        g:R/P \longrightarrow R_P/PR_P \\
        \bar{r} \longmapsto \frac{\bar{r}}{1}
    \end{gather*}
$$

is an isomorphism.

I've already proved it is a homomorphism, well-defined, and injective. When it comes to trying to prove it is surjective, I have this:

If $\frac{a}{b} \in PR_P$, this means $a\in P$, then it is obvious $\frac{a}{1} \in PR_P$. Then, I  know that for any $\frac{a}{b} \in PR_P$, its pre-image will be $a$.

I struggle with $\frac{a}{b} \not \in PR_P$, as I don't know how to prove it has a pre-image. I tried seeing if $\frac{\bar{a}}{1} = \frac{\bar{a}}{b}$. I know that $a \not \in P$, then $a + P \neq P$. But since I want $\frac{\bar{a}}{1} = \frac{\bar{a}}{b}$, I want to see if there's a $\frac{p}{s} \in PR_P$, that is, $p\in P, s \not \in P$, such that either:
$$
\begin{gather*}
\frac{a}{1} = \frac{a}{b} + \frac{p}{s}\\
\text{or}\\
\frac{a}{b} = \frac{a}{1} + \frac{p}{s}\\
\end{gather*}
$$

In the first case, doing the usual addition would give me $\frac{a}{1} = \frac{as + bp}{bs}$, which would need $bs = 1$ and I don't know how to prove that.

I've been trying with the second case, in which $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{as + p}{s} $, which implies $s=b$, then I have to prove that $a = ab + p$.  When trying to do this, I end up with $a - ab = p$, but this implies $a-ab \in P$, and I don't know how to see if this is true.

I have also proved that $PR_P$ contains all the not-invertible elements of $R_P$. That is, $PR_P = R_P - R^*_P$. Also, I know that $PR_P$ is a maximal ideal in $R_P$

Any hints?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: I have added an answer. If u dont agree with it reply in the comments below answer and we shall discuss. Cheers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$as+bp = (a'+p')bs \iff (a-a'b)s \in P \iff a-a'b \in P \iff a \in <b>/P \iff a \in <b,P>$

This is true for any $a,b$ iff $P$ is a maximal ideal as in that case $<b,P> =R$ and hence $a\in <b,P> =R.$

So you have surjection iff $P$ is a maximal ideal in $R$.

Comment: Thanks! But I can't understand where the equation $as+bp=(a′+p′)bs$ comes from, or how you derive the first equivalence. Other than that, I get everything.

Comment: $a/b + p/s = (a'+p')/1$ is the first equation.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks! And where does that first equivalence come from? How can I know that $(a-a'b)s \in P$?

Comment: This is because $(a-a'b)s =p'bs-pb \in P$ since $p,p' \in P$ and $P$ is an ideal.

Comment: I get it. Thanks a lot! I don't know if $P$ is a maximal, but I think I have an idea of what to do. Again, many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to prove that the map  $$
>      \begin{gather*}
>          g:R/P \longrightarrow R_P/PR_P \\
>          \bar{r} \longmapsto \frac{\bar{r}}{1}
>      \end{gather*} $$
> is an isomorphism.

This is hopeless though, right? The second thing is always a field and the first one is not necessarily a field.  For example, let $R=\mathbb Z$ and $P=\{0\}$.

Incidentally, this also shows it is not always possible to define a surjective map between the two, because there's no surjective ring homomorphism of $\mathbb Z$ onto $\mathbb Q$.